# Airflow Deadlock while running multiple nodes in parallel in a SubDAG

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, airflow, database-deadlocks

**DAG structure:** We have an ETL pipeline having a number of phases. Each phase could have child phases inside it, which is true recursively as well (to a known depth, about 3-4). The inner most layer consists of SQLs (largely variable number, avg about 30), either executing in parallel or serial fashion or both.

For each phase, we have used SubDAG. 

We are aware that using SubDAGs is a bad practice, but because of our hierarchical structure, they become a natural choice. We are using *Celery Executor for SubDAGs*.

For the leaf nodes in the innermost layer, we have a custom operator.

**Problem:** We (very) occasionally hit a deadlock and the SubDAG task which houses the SQL nodes, fails. There are no child node failures.

**Error:** `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')`

**StackTrace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py", line 102, in execute
    executor=self.executor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1284, in run
    job.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 222, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 769, in _execute
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 699, in _execute_for_run_dates
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 586, in _process_backfill_task_instances
    _per_task_process(task, key, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 508, in _per_task_process
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2479, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2617, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2577, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 236, in save_obj
    update,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 996, in _emit_update_statements
    statement, multiparams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
[SQL: UPDATE task_instance SET state=%s, queued_dttm=%s WHERE task_instance.task_id = %s AND task_instance.dag_id = %s AND task_instance.execution_date = %s]
[parameters: ('queued', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 10, 51, 48, 301880, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 'SQL_W', 'RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 10, 28, 36, 123853, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Additionally, we also see a warning in the logs as below.

```
[2020-01-14 10:51:43,217] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-14 10:51:43,217] {backfill_job.py:246}
WARNING - ('RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ', 'SQL_A', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 10, 28, 36, 123853, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1) state success not in running=dict_values(
[<TaskInstance: RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ.SQL_B 2020-01-14 10:28:36.123853+00:00 [running]>,
<TaskInstance: RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ.SQL_C 2020-01-14 10:28:36.123853+00:00 [running]>,
<TaskInstance: RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ.SQL_D 2020-01-14 10:28:36.123853+00:00 [running]>,
<TaskInstance: RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ.SQL_E 2020-01-14 10:28:36.123853+00:00 [running]>,
<TaskInstance: RANDOM_DAG_ID.PhaseX.PhaseY.PhaseZ.SQL_F 2020-01-14 10:28:36.123853+00:00 [running]>])
```

**Airflow Version:** 1.10.5, 1.10.7


We found that [AIRFLOW-2516](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2516) is the issue we are facing, [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2516?focusedCommentId=17005465&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17005465) comment pointing to the probable cause. It suggests the deadlock is due to two queries acquiring locks on two indices in different order.

Dropping the second index on task state may not be a good idea as it would affect Airflow Scheduler performance, which is already not great.

They seem to have made fix for deadlock at the main DAG level, not at the SubDAG level.

We have tried auto-retrying the same SubDAG operator after a minute, using BaseOperator parameter `retries`, but in good number of cases, the deadlock happens in the retry as well.

The same issue could occur even if we remove SubDAGs, which will not be a trivial exercise for us.

Any lateral solutions/workarounds are also welcome.

Please let me know if airflow.cfg file is required.

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` so we can see the deadlock. Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved.